# Which article is correct? The king left an/the heir

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Which one is correct and why?

> The king left an heir.

or

> The king left the heir.

Comment: Hello Raj and welcome to ELL! On this site, we expect people asking questions to have done some research on their own before asking. This could mean doing a simple Internet search. Can you tell us what research you have done, what you found, and why you're still unsure? Also, please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Both are grammatical.

They have different meanings, and either might be appropriate in context.

By far the more likely is *the king left an heir*, because "an heir" is new in the discourse, and is most often qualified with an indefinite article.

If you said *The king left the heir*, this imply that the heir has already been discussed (and probably identified) in the discourse.